# Pipe the echo in remote ssh

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh

I have a script that I didn’t write. When it is run, it outputs some information, then expects the user to press enter, and then outputs the last part of the information. This is what I need.
I need to get that last part i.e. last line of output programmatically.
When I run the script locally as follows:

```
RESULT=$(echo -ne '\n' | script $param)
```

I can get the output and process it, but when I try to run the same remotely i.e.

```
RESULT=$(echo -ne '\n' | ssh remoteserver script $param)
```

The script hangs. It Seems that the pipe of the new line does not work for the remote ssh.

How can I fix this?

**Update:**
The script takes input from terminal directly and is a perl script, just in case it matters

Comment: Are you able to modify the script to comment out the `read` that temporarily stops the script?

Comment: What do you get if you run `ssh remoteserver script $param` as the same user with the same values as the script would do so?

Comment: @Kusalananda:No I can't control that

Comment: @roaima:Some information, prompt to press enter, some more information

Comment: Sounds like it should be easily fixed by removing the thing that outputs the prompts and waits for user input. If that's not possible in the script because of permissions, then it will be possible in a copy of the script.

Comment: Also, running `ssh` with stdin redirected from `/dev/null`, either explicitly or with `ssh -n` would probably solve it.  The `read` would fail, but I doubt that the script actually cares.

Comment: I wonder if script is getting input from stdin, or is accessing terminal direct. If so this is rude and not the Unix may (editors do this, but that is OK).

Comment: What happens when you add the `-t` option to `ssh`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor:Nothing different

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor:It is getting it from terminal

Comment: @jim from terminal or standard input or don't know?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor:from terminal input

Comment: So the echo pipe will not work, local or remote. Did the answer below work?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: How I finally made it work was: `ssh -T server<<EOF echo -ne '\n' | script param EOF`. I will test the answer too, just saw that.

Answer (score 1):

Fake a terminal and "type" the required data. First up our test program `testproggie` on the remote system

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.14.0;
use warnings;

say "one thing";

open my $fh, '<', '/dev/tty' or die "nope on /dev/tty: $!\n";
readline $fh;

say "another thing";
```

Which will indeed fail if you remote a newline to it

```
$ printf "\n" | ssh test.example.edu ./testproggie
one thing
nope on /dev/tty: No such device or address
$
```

So now we fake a terminal with `remotenl` on the local system

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

#set timeout 999
#match_max 99999

# this assumes the remote side does not do anything silly with
# the shell; if it does you may need to spawn a remote shell
# and then {send "./testproggie\r"} to that and then...
spawn -noecho ssh -q -t test.example.edu ./testproggie
# this can be improved if you know what the line before the
# wait-for-the-return-key will contain
expect -re .
send "\r"
expect eof

# this could be simplified with better expect calls, above
regexp {([^\r\n]+)\r\n$} $expect_out(buffer) unused lastline
puts ">>>$lastline<<<"
```

and run it

```
$ ./remotenl
one thing

another thing
>>>another thing<<<
$
```